# Vue.js: how to use a variables from laravel predifined _variables.scss file?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with Vue.js 2.
In a vue component, I would like to use a variable specified in the document `\ressources\assets\sass\_variables.scss`.

This is my code:

```
<template>
 ...
<template>
<style lang="sass">
  #note
    color: $brand-info
</style>
```

This variable file is imported in the file `\ressources\assets\sass\app.scss`

On compiling, npm returns the following error:

```
> Module build failed: 
>         color: $brand-info
>           ^
>       Undefined variable: "$brand-info".
>       in C:\www\projects\crm\resources\assets\js\components\person-show.vue
> (line 150, column 12)
```

If I replace `$brand-info` by `red`, it compiles with no errors.

How is it possible to use this variable?
Any hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to import your `app.scss` file into the style section of your component.

Comment: @thanksd the compiled version of app.scss (app.css) is already imported where the component is used.

Comment: The scope of the component's style section doesn't take into account its parent's scope. To my knowledge, you need to either define sass variables in the component's scope or import them from a specified file.

Comment: @Wario are you using webpack?

Comment: @thanksd yes I'm using webpack. In which I have : 
` mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();`

Comment: Do you have an alias to your assets folder in your webpack config file?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'alias'. In my php files, I use mix('css/app.css'). Don't know how to do the same in js :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not importing the `app.scss` file in your component's style section, so it doesn't have references to any of the variables defined in it.

You can import that file into your Vue component's style section like so:

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import '../../sass/app';

  #note
    color: $brand-info
</style>
```

Comment: It returns the following error : ` error  in ./resources/assets/js/components/person-show.vue

Module build failed: 
    @import '../../../sass/app.scss';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../sass/app.scss.
Parent style sheet: stdin
      in C:\www\projects\crm\resources\assets\js\components\person-show.vue (line 147, column 1)`

Comment: Whoops, it'd just be `'../../sass/app.scss'`

Comment: Unless you're using webpack and then it'd be better to alias the `assets` folder so you don't need to use relative paths

Comment: you were right. just no need to specify the .scss extension. Thanks - d :D